# Long-lived connections (asynchronous server push) with Apache/PHP/Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, apache

I come from more of a Java background.  In the last year or two, it's become somewhat popular to do [server push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) over HTTP using [long-lived HTTP connections in Comet](http://blogs.oracle.com/andi/entry/comet_basics).  It's an extremely useful technique.

So I'm curious what the equivalent is with Apache + PHP + Javascript?  One option I see is just using straight AJAX calls (eg with jQuery) but I don't really know how Apache handles them or how I can implement such a thing on the serverside with PHP.  Any ideas?  Any good resources on this kind of thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Comet programming techniques in PHP.  I think a good place to start is this [post](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start), describing how to implement Comet in PHP.